# Can't change backgroundTint programmatically

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles, material-components, material-components-android

Android Studio 3.6

in my styles. xml

```
 <style name="buttonStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_button_textColor</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/button_bg_color</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="buttonClickStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_bg_color</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/button_click_bg_color</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>
```

in xml layout:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonStartSearchBluetooth"
            style="@style/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
            android:onClick="onClickButtonStartSearch"
            android:text="@string/start_search"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

When click button I try to change style like this:

```
dataBinding.buttonStartSearchBluetooth.setTextAppearance(R.style.buttonClickStyle)
```

But it change only text color. Not change `backgroundTint`

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change programmatically the text color and the background color use:

- the method [**`setBackgroundTintList`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) to change the background color selector.
- the method `setTextColor` to change the text color

Something like:

```
    button.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.button_selector));
    button.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color....));
```

In any case there are some issues in your style.

- use a `MaterialComponents.Button.*` [style](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#styles) as parent
- use `backgroundTint` instead of `android:backgroundTint`
- use `android:textAppearance` to define your text style

Something like:

```
<style name="buttonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/default_button_textColor</item>
  <item name="backgroundTint">@color/my_selector</item>
  <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/my_textAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="my_textAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You forgot to use "button.setTextAppearance(R.style.buttonStyle)" to change text color of button "on fly"

Comment: @a_subscriber In your question you asked how to change the background color. In any case use `button.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color....));`.

Answer (score 8):

Use this code to change MaterialComponents Button Background tint color.

```
yourbutton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor(color)));
```

Comment: this is the answer!

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
yourbutton.setBackgroundTintList(contextInstance.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_xml_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTextAppearance` only take care about styling the Text of the TextView not the background. Check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextAppearance) to see supported property that `setTextAppearance` affected.